# Como puedo agregar un cuadro de dialogo y que agarre la posicion de mi adapter de un setOnclickListener de mi recycleview en android

Tags: android, recyclerview, alertdialog

aqui agarra la posicion a cual hará la accion de actualizar

```
   AsistentesConAdapter adapter = new AsistentesConAdapter(listaasistencia);
        
                    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
        
        
                            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                            pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
                            pDialog.show();
        
                            String ip=getString(R.string.ip);
        
                            String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/JSONActualizarEstados.php?DOCUMENTO="+listaasistencia.get(recycleAsistencia.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getNombres().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se ha Actualizado el estado con exito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
        
                            stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    pDialog.hide();
        
                                    if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("elimina")){
        
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se ha Eliminado con exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }else{
                                        if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("noExiste")){
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se encuentra la persona ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                                        }else{
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"actualizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                                        }
        
                                    }
        
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha podido conectar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    pDialog.hide();
                                }
                            });
                            request.add(stringRequest);
        
                        }
                    });
```

este es el dialogo que cree.. quisiera que antes de q actualice el
estado de la persona me salga si estoy seguro de hacerlo  alguien me
podría ayudar ............

```
 public AlertDialog dialogoActualizar(){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Actualizar Asistencia").setMessage("¿ Estás seguro de cambiar el estado ?").
                        setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // no hace nada
                            }
        
        
                }).setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        
                            }
                        });
                return builder.create();
        
}
```

Comment: Hola edu, te invito a que hagas  el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la posición del elemento, se debe realizar dentro del `Adapter`.

Para realizar lo que deseas, implementa `OnClickListener` en tu clase "Holder", en el método `onClick()` puedes utilizar el método [getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) para obtener la posición del elemento, ahí puedes llamar tu diálogo.

Ejemplo:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
      implements View.OnClickListener{
    

   public MyViewHolder(View view){
      ...
      ...
   } 

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clic en posición: " + getAbsoluteAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      dialogoActualizar();    
        
   }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió

Comment: Si esta pregunta solucionó el problema, puedes marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.